# if/else if equivalent for qmake/pro Qt file

Tags: qt, if-statement, qmake

I sometimes have to write qmake pro file like this:

```
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += activate

macos {
    clear_cache.commands += defaults write io.delille.$$TARGET activated 1;
}

win32 {
    clear_cache.commands += another working command;
}


linux {
    clear_cache.commands += echo unsupported;
}

ios {
    clear_cache.commands += echo unsupported;
}
```

Is there a way to have avoid listing all unsupported plateform in a simpler way like most language allow if `if`/`else if` statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

qmake knowns about if/else: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#scopes

```
win32:xml {
    message(Building for Windows)
    SOURCES += xmlhandler_win.cpp
} else:xml {
    SOURCES += xmlhandler.cpp
} else {
    message("Unknown configuration")
}
```