# How to do an else block for `contains` in qmake

Tags: qt, qmake, qt5.15

I have a qmake varaible defined in a `.pro` file like below.

```
DEFINES += SOME_VAR_STATE
```

I know that using `contains` I can check if `SOME_VAR_STATE` is defined or not by doing something like below.

```
contains(DEFINES, SOME_VAR_STATE) {
    # Do something
}

!contains(DEFINES, SOME_VAR_STATE) {
    # Do something else
}
```

How do I write an else case for the `contains` block? I don't want to write 2 blocks like done above. Instead of writing `contains` and `!contains` separately, I want to write an else block for `contains`. How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if/else if equivalent for qmake/pro Qt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898385/if-else-if-equivalent-for-qmake-pro-qt-file)

Comment: It does not answer my question

Comment: Can you just use the contains as an if-expression? `if (contains(DEFINES, SOME_VAR_STATE)) {} else {}`?